# solidity cant deposit 1.1 (float ether value)

Tags: solidity, tokens, fallback-function

hi this is my contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;


contract TrusteeFinTestToken {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 ethtstraito = 100;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function TrusteeFinTestToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {

        initialSupply = 10000000000 ;
        tokenName ="TrustiFintraTest";
        tokenSymbol="TFINT";
        decimalUnits = 4;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
        transferFromUser(this,initialSupply);

        }

    function setETHTokenTokenRaito(uint256 newRaito){
        ethtstraito = newRaito;
    }

    function() public payable{

        transferFromContract(msg.sender,msg.value/1000000000000000000*ethtstraito*10000);
    }

    function contractETHbalance() constant returns(uint256) {
        return this.balance;
        }

    /* Send coins */
    function transferFromUser(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }
        function transferFromContract(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[this] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[this] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(this, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }
}
```

when i send deposit 1 eth to fallback
its return me 100 Tokens
but when i deposit 1.1 ehter or other float value
contract doesn't work 
and show no errors 
what is the problem

Comment: You should read the Solidity manual: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Multiply first, divide last (or you lose information).**

Change this:

```
msg.value/1000000000000000000*ethtstraito*10000
```

To this:

```
msg.value*ethtstraito*10000/1000000000000000000
```

Or better yet, to this:

```
msg.value*ethtstraito/100000000000000
```

Or even better yet, to this:

```
mul(msg.value,ethtstraito)/100000000000000
```

With `mul` being:

```
function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: Or better even better yet, to this: `mul(msg.value,ethtstraito) * (uint256(10) ** decimals) / (uint256(10) ** 18)` in case the amount of decimals changes later on.

Comment: @JesseBusman: That will not compile. Also, even after you fix the compilation errors, with this code there's a higher chance of arithmetic overflow (hence failure of the operation). You could argue that the chances aren't that much higher, still, weighing all the factors, I wouldn't call it "better" just for the use of `decimals` (when the chances of an overflow are slightly higher due to that).

Comment: Tnx A lot It's Work